# Why wont my browser recognise php scripts within a html file?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am designing a website that requires me to show the outputs of a mysql database on a webpage written in html. However my browser doesn't seem to recognize the php scripts within the html file and returns blank values where their should be details. The scripts worked fine in the .php files but have no effect when included in the .html files even after creating a .htaccess file as instructed in previously asked questions. Is there anything else that can be done to solve this issue?

Comment: There are different ways of triggering PHP scripts to run in files with a .HTML extension, depending on the configuration of your server.

Comment: Is the file extension if your _html_  page `.php`?

Comment: Browsers don't care about php scripts. You need to configure your server to treat `.html` files as php.

Comment: *The browser* doesn't execute PHP code.  If the PHP code is being sent to the browser at all then either your PHP server isn't configured correctly or you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Save your file with .php extension

Comment: @AhsN no, the extension is .html

Comment: @Vatev how do i do that?

Comment: @AustinRoy Any file containing php code need to be saved with the ".php" extension so that the server knows it contains server side scripting language that needs to be interpreted before the page is actually sent to the server as html. Since your file is ".html", the server doesn't executes any php scripts it might contain.

Comment: @AhsN thanks...saving as a .php code worked in the end

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods (that I've encountered) of changing the environment on an Apache server via .htaccess to allow PHP scripts to be processed in .html files, depending on the configuation. Whichever of these you've attempted, try the other.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php .html .htm
```

Or

```
AddHandler cgi-script .html 
SetEnv PHP_EXTENSION .html
```

Comment: I tried the first mthod and it didnt seem to have any effect, I will give the second one a try. Hopefully it will work. Thanks